# How to create an loop that will implement my XML lines the amount of times i want it

Tags: c#, xml, loops, foreach

Is there any way where I can make an loop of an whatever size and it will loop over the number given and add the XML elements. The first part of the code should remain like this and the down part should be dynamic.

```
string name = "haus";
XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument(
  new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
  new XElement("Document",
    new XElement("DocumentInfo",
      new XElement("Created", "2022-02-09T13:52:07.8908726Z"),
      new XElement("ExportSetting", "WithDefaults"),
      new XElement("InstalledProducts",
        new XElement("Product",
          new XElement("DisplayName", "Totally Integrated Automation Portal"),
          new XElement("DisplayVersion", "V16")
        ),
        new XElement("OptionPackage",
          new XElement("DisplayName", "TIA Portal Version Control Interface"),
          new XElement("ObjectList",
            new XElement("MultilingualText", 
              new XAttribute("ID", 1), 
              new XAttribute("CompositionName", "Comment"),
              new XElement("ObjectList",
                new XElement("MultilingualTextItem", 
                  new XAttribute("ID", 2), 
                  new XAttribute("CompositionName", "Items"),
                  new XElement("AttributeList",
                    new XElement("Culture", "de-DE"),
                    new XElement("Text")
                  )
                )
              )
            ),
            // From here it should do this for the given number for example 10
            new XElement("Hmi.TextGraphicList.TextListEntry", 
              new XAttribute("ID", 3), 
              new XAttribute("CompositionName", "Entries"),
              new XElement("AttributeList",
                new XElement("DefaultEntry", "false"),
                new XElement("EntryType","SingleValue"),
                new XElement("From","0"),  // this number should go up by one after every example
                new XElement ("To","0") // same with this
              ),  
              new XElement("ObjectList",
                new XElement("MultilingualText", 
                  new XAttribute("ID", 4), 
                  new XAttribute("CompositionName", "Text"),
                  new XElement("ObjectList",
                    new XElement("MultilingualTextItem", 
                      new XAttribute("ID", 5), 
                      new XAttribute("CompositionName", "Items"),
                      new XElement("AttributeList",
                        new XElement("Culture","de-DE"),
                        new XElement("Text",
                          new XElement("body",
                            new XElement("p","kein 0")
                          )
                        )
                      )
                    )
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);

xmlDocument.Save(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tools\VisualStudioProjects\CustomersDetails.xml");
```

Comment: Put this code inside a method that has a parameter for the values you require? Though, to be honest, I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip. I dont know how to ask properly.  I want the code from my commment upwards to reamain same becouse its always same. Under the comment it should create the same code mulitple times for the amount of times i want it. Like i want 10x and it will do the first part once and add 10x the last part. I dont know if its clearer know.

Comment: Yes, that's clearer - wasn't quite what I initially thought, but the answer given below is how I'd have done it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of `Enumerable.Range` and `Select` to generate the repeated XML elements:

```
XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument(
  new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
  new XElement("Document",
    new XElement("DocumentInfo",
      new XElement("Created", "2022-02-09T13:52:07.8908726Z"),
      new XElement("ExportSetting", "WithDefaults"),
      new XElement("InstalledProducts",
        new XElement("Product",
          new XElement("DisplayName", "Totally Integrated Automation Portal"),
          new XElement("DisplayVersion", "V16")
        ),
        new XElement("OptionPackage",
          new XElement("DisplayName", "TIA Portal Version Control Interface"),
          new XElement("ObjectList",
            new XElement("MultilingualText", 
              new XAttribute("ID", 1), 
              new XAttribute("CompositionName", "Comment"),
              new XElement("ObjectList",
                new XElement("MultilingualTextItem", 
                  new XAttribute("ID", 2), 
                  new XAttribute("CompositionName", "Items"),
                  new XElement("AttributeList",
                    new XElement("Culture", "de-DE"),
                    new XElement("Text")
                  )
                )
              )
            ),
            Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new XElement("Hmi.TextGraphicList.TextListEntry", 
              new XAttribute("ID", 3), 
              new XAttribute("CompositionName", "Entries"),
              new XElement("AttributeList",
                new XElement("DefaultEntry", "false"),
                new XElement("EntryType","SingleValue"),
                new XElement("From", i),
                new XElement ("To", i)
              ),  
              new XElement("ObjectList",
                new XElement("MultilingualText", 
                  new XAttribute("ID", 4), 
                  new XAttribute("CompositionName", "Text"),
                  new XElement("ObjectList",
                    new XElement("MultilingualTextItem", 
                      new XAttribute("ID", 5), 
                      new XAttribute("CompositionName", "Items"),
                      new XElement("AttributeList",
                        new XElement("Culture","de-DE"),
                        new XElement("Text",
                          new XElement("body",
                            new XElement("p","kein 0")
                          )
                        )
                      )
                    )
                  )
                )
              )
            ))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```